# Bootstrap Carousel is not working with the AngularJS

Tags: javascript, angularjs, twitter-bootstrap, carousel

I applied bootstrap carousel in my 1st view which is rendering through the routing ,but as soon as i m hitting my carousel next or prev button it routes to the view ,routing or bootstrap href is intercepting i tried all the answers which have given in stackoverflow but it is not working.
I dont want apply angular-ui-bootstrap third party .
Here is my code.

```
<div class="container"  ng-controller="OrdersController">
     <!--carousel start -->
    <div id="mycarousel" class="carousel slide" data-ride="carousel">
  <!-- Menu -->
 <ol class="carousel-indicators">
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="0" class="active"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="1"></li>
    <li data-target="#carousel" data-slide-to="2"></li>
 </ol>

<!-- Items -->
<div class="carousel-inner">
    <div class="carousel-item active">
        <img src="http://gallery.thesemite.com/var/albums/Nepal-2012/IMG_0848.jpg?m=1342483083" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://upload.wikimedia.org/wikipedia/commons/2/2b/Savonlinna_hein%C3%A4kuu_2002_IMG_1635.JPG" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
    <div class="carousel-item">
        <img src="http://gsm2015.ru/wp-content/uploads/2013/07/IMG_2013_21.jpg" class="img-responsive"/>
    </div>
</div> 

<a class="left carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="prev">
<span class="icon-prev" aria-hidden="true"></span>
<span class="sr-only">Previous</span>
</a>
 <a class="right carousel-control" href="#carousel-example-generic" role="button" data-slide="next">
<span class="icon-next" aria-hidden="true"></span>
  <span class="sr-only">Next</span>
  </a>
 </div>
   <!--carousel end-->
  </div>
```

and i tried removing anchor tag and href attribute and replacing with span and data-target which is not working i tried all the scenarios like calling a function by  ng-click="prevSlide()"

```
       //this function inside the controller
    $scope.prevSlide = function() {
       $('#mycarousel').carousel('next');
    };
```

which is also not working any help would be grateful as tried a lot writing comments everywhere but didn't get the answer.

Comment: Why do you not want to use Angular UI Bootstrap? It's a component by the Bootstrap guys made to work with Angular. (and bootstrap is a 3rd party component just as any component not actually made by Angular)

Comment: Hi ashishSober, was this issue solved for you?

Answer (score 0):

Please Change  $ to jQuery something like this jQueryscope.prevSlide. Hope it will help you.